# How to move the game object according the movement of real world object in the web cam in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

i want to develop a tan gram game in unity with the concept of augmented reality. i want to make tan gram figures using real tan grams in front of a webcam ,according to the tan gram figure in the screen. For that i want to place the game object with respect to the real tan gram in the camera frame. i also want to change the position and angle accordingly. please suggest a way to achive this. Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With difficulty.

If you want to do this without some sort of custom built hardware controller on the real tan gram, you will need some quite intricate image processing techniques. The following are some vague steps and pointers to achieve what you want. If there is a better option I cannot think of it, but this is very conceptual and by no means guaranteed to work - Just how I would attempt the task if I really had to.

1. Use a Laplacian operator on the image to calculate the edges
2. Use this, along with the average colour information in pixels to the left/right and above/below of each "edge" pixel (within a certain tolerance) to detect the individual shapes, corners, and relative positions starting from the centre of the image.
3. Calculate the relative sizes of each shape and and approximate the rotation using basic trigonometry.

However I can't help but feel like this is an incredibly large amount of work for such a concept, and could be so intensive to calculate this for each pixel to make it truly not worth your time. Furthermore it depends a lot on the quality of the camera used, and parallax errors would probably be nightmarish to resolve. Unless you are truly committed to this idea, I would either search for some pre-existing asset that does this for you or not undertake the project.